# ajax JSON call returning array of strings instead of objects

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

When I do the ajax call I am parsing the json_encoded data and when I log the data to the console it's actually an array of strings instead of objects. It's showing this.

```
[  
"{"   todoText":"dgdgdfgdfgdf",
"completed":false,
"editable":false
 }",

"{  
"todoText":"test 2",
"completed":false,
"editable":false
}",

"{  
"todoText":"test 3",
"completed":false,
"editable":false
}", 

"{  
"todoText":"sdfsdf",
"completed":false,
"editable":false
}"
]
```

This is the code I used to make the call to retrieve the data.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$.get("php/listtasks.php", function(data){

var parsed = JSON.parse(data);


  $('#directions').html(parsed[0]);

  console.log(parsed);
})

});
```

This is the php code i used to encode the data and echo it back to the javascript.

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM list";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);

$rows = $result->num_rows;


for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
{
$result->data_seek($j);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);


$x[$j] = $row[2];


}

echo json_encode($x);
```

Comment: have you tried: setting mimetype in php to json? and/or `console.log(data)` before/without `JSON.parse`?

Comment: @Jeff that outputs almost the same thing only now it has foward slashes throughout it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, your `$row[2]` is a JSON object so you need to decode it like this:

```
$x[$j] = json_decode($row[2]);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works! I am just wondering if you can explain what happened. So first I stringifyed an object in javascript and sent an ajax request to send it to the server side.I then inserted this into a row in a mysql table. Why is that i have to decode that row just to encode it again to send it back?

Comment: `$row[2]` is a field, not row and is stored as a string (stringifyed object). I need to see your code in order to provide a detailed explanation !

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$x[$j] = $row[2];
```

With

```
$x[$j] = json_decode($row[2]);
```